# Django: Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use username.set() instead

Tags: python, django, django-models

I have some troubles with migrating my database in django

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 15, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "E:\Env\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 381, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "E:\Env\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 375, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "E:\Env\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 316, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "E:\Env\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 350, in execute
    self.check()
  File "E:\Env\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 379, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "E:\Env\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 366, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "E:\Env\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\core\checks\registry.py", line 71, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "E:\Env\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\checks.py", line 74, in check_user_model
    if isinstance(cls().is_anonymous, MethodType):
  File "E:\Env\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 470, in __init__
    _setattr(self, field.attname, val)
  File "E:\Env\Python\Python37-32\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields\related_descriptors.py", line 537, in __set__
    % self._get_set_deprecation_msg_params(),
TypeError: Direct assignment to the reverse side of a related set is prohibited. Use username.set() instead.
```

Here is my models.py:

```
class PostComments(models.Model):
    post = models.ForeignKey(InfoPost, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='comments')
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="username")
    text = models.TextField()
    created_date = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
    #approved_comment = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    reply_to = models.ForeignKey("self", null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name='replies')

    #def __str__(self): return 'Comment by {} on {}'.format(self.name, self.post)
```

I am trying to make comments system for post in my website, but there is some error occured. I don't know whats wrong with my model, but if i try to make migrations without my new PostComments model, its migrating pretty fine.

**UPD. Here is my code, where i am using my PostComments model**

```
forms.py
    class CommentsForm(forms.ModelForm):
        post = forms.CharField(required=False)
        author = forms.CharField(required=False)

        class Meta:
            model = PostComments
            fields = '__all__'
```

views.py

```
def post(request, slug):
    post = get_object_or_404(InfoPost, slug=slug)
    comment_list = CommentsForm._meta.model.objects.all()

    if request.user.is_authenticated:
        user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)

        if request.method == 'POST':
            comment = CommentsForm(request.POST)
            print(comment.is_valid())
            if comment.is_valid():
                com = comment.save(commit=False)
                com.author = request.user
                com.post = post
                com.save()
                return redirect('post', slug=slug)
        else:
            comment_form = CommentsForm()
        return render_to_response('MainPage/Post.html',
                                  {'post': post, "user": user, 'img_w': image_w, 'img_h': image_h,
                                   'comments_list': comment_list, 'comment_form': comment_form})

    return render_to_response('MainPage/Post.html', {'post': post, 'img_w': image_w, 'img_h': image_h, 'comments_list': comment_list})
```

I was thinking, its started after i tried to get all objects of comments for displaying them in view, but i don't really know

Comment: Can you share the code where you are using the model?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are shielding the actual `username` field on the `User` model with the `related_name` on the author ForeignKey.

It should be like this:

```
author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="usernames")
```

'*related_name=**usernames***' at plural.

The reason why it failed is because when you did:

```
user = User.objects.get(username=request.user.username)
```

you were basically accessing the reverse relation to the comments set that are tied to the user, not the actual `username` field (which I assume is a CharField).

More info about related_name in the [django documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/db/queries/#following-relationships-backward).

Comment: Okey, its fixed my name. I don't even know about that, thank you

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why you have set post and author to CharFields, when the model has foreign keys. Especially as you are setting then directly in the model anyway.

You should remove those definitions, and then exclude the fields from the form altogether:

```
class CommentsForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = PostComments
        exclude = ("post", "author")
```

Comment: That was only becouse i want to use this fields in my template while generating comment list. So, i was thinking it's a good idea

Comment: Well, no, it's not a good idea, and is probably the source of your problem.

Comment: But the problem was my "related_name" was not names properly in my model, so i just renamed it and its fixed my problem. But i've maked as you tells in answer